# Problems with pushing object into array CSS | JS | HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

Im creating a module where information (exam information) is stored in an array, and passed through to another js using localstorage. The problem i get is the previous exam always gets overwritten even though i am using .push. All the variables are defined elsewhere. Thanks for the help. Here is the code:

```
recentexamdb = []
document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    document.getElementById("maindiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("buttondiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("countdown").style.visibility= "visible";
    var yearinput = document.getElementById("yearinput").value;
    var minuteinput = document.getElementById("minuteinput").value;
    var hourinput = document.getElementById("hourinput").value;
    var secondinput = document.getElementById("secondinput").value;
    var twentyminutes = new Audio('20mins.mp3');
    var tenminutes = new Audio('10mins.mp3');
    var fiveminutes = new Audio('5mins.mp3');
    var timesup = new Audio('timesup.mp3');
    var firstalert = document.getElementById("firstalertinput").value;
    var secondalert = document.getElementById("secondalertinput").value;
    var thirdalert = document.getElementById("thirdalertinput").value;
    var readingalert = document.getElementById("readingalertinput").value;
    var timetotal = (Number(hourinput)*60) + Number(minuteinput)
    enddate = (new Date().getTime()) + (minuteinput*60000) +(secondinput*1000) + (hourinput*3600000);
    var examtypeinput = document.getElementById("examtypeinput").value;
    var hours=0;
    var minutes=0;
    var seconds=0;
    var countdown = document.getElementById("countdown");
    var examtype = document.getElementById("examtype");

 setInterval(function () {
        var currentdate = new Date().getTime();
        var secondsleft = (enddate - currentdate) / 1000;
        // do some time calculations
        hours = parseInt(secondsleft / 3600);
        secondsleft = secondsleft % 3600;
        minutes = parseInt(secondsleft / 60);
        seconds = parseInt(secondsleft % 60);
        if (hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
          document.getElementById("countdowndiv").style.fontFamily = "Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif"
          document.getElementById("countdowndiv").style.fontSize = "100%"
          countdown.innerHTML = "Time is up! Pens down and wait for further instruction"
          examtype.innerHTML = "If you continue to write, marks may be deducted"
          var readingtimenow = "No reading time selected"
          var timetotalnow = ((hours * 60) + minutes)
          var examinfoobject = {
            year: yearinput,
            examtime: timetotalnow,
            timeofexam: Date(),
            examtype: examtypeinput,
            readingtime: readingtimenow
          }
          recentexamdb.push(examinfoobject)
          console.log(recentexamdb)
          localStorage.setItem("storedexamdb", JSON.stringify(recentexamdb))
      }
}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Please provide the whole relevant code.

Comment: Have you declared recentexamdb as an array?

Comment: Added rest of code

Comment: can you create a fiddle please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting the syntax specific to JS, (thanks for pointing out)
First initialize the "recentexamdb" from existing value in local storage, otherwise it will always be a new array & earlier saved values may be lost.

```
recentexamdb=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("storedexamdb")); // read  already saved values
 recentexamdb.push(examinfoobject);
 localStorage.setItem("storedexamdb",JSON.stringify(recentexamdb));
```

On next page, you can 
Hope this helps.

Comment: why are you giving angular answer ? it is javascript question

Comment: Doesnt seem to work. I added it like stated after the examinfoobject, and declared the variable at the start of the project. I get this error : timermodule.js:319 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null. line 319 was at recentexamdb.push(examinfoobject)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed due to aarati's answer. It worked when i set a localstorage clickcounter and only used the already saved values when the clickcounter was >1